# How to handle continuous deployment with docker compose and database services?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, continuous-deployment, circleci

I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to handle deployment changes on database services. Right now, it's as simple as doing:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

It rebuilds the containers if there's a change on the config. It's not a problem for my web service (node) since it doesn't have any sort of state. I can pretty much delete everything, bring it back up again and nothing is lost.

My database service is continuously registering new data which is obviously important so i can't just scrap it. As far as I understand, volumes are different every time the images get built. So I would lose all the data every time I rebuild the service.

How should I deal with scheme changes? Or should I update the service manually?

Comment: I would not containerize a database server.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a data volume to your container. In this case, you can add a "volumes" properties in you `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
volumes:
  - /opt/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Then the data will be volumed in `/opt/mysql/data` on the host.

Comment: See also http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-with-docker-performance-characteristics/

Comment: This is part of the `volumes` key on the service right? I still don't know how would I deal with the scheme changes.